# How to get the memory size of an object in dolphindb?

Tags: database, vector, dolphindb

How to get the memory size of an object in dolphindb?

I define a vector v:

```
v=1..1000000
```

Now I want to know the memory size of v. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the memory size occupied by an object through the memSize function. The sample code is as follows:

```py
v=1..1000000
select bytes from objs() where name =  `v
```

The return result is:

```py
4000000
```